# JS extract / use context from function in arguments object

Tags: javascript

Could one extract and use the context of a bound function from another passed callback function for example

```
var person = {

   name : 'David',

   save : function(){

      API( function(){ // this is the callback function bound to this
         console.log( this.name ) // David
      }.bind(this))

   }

}

var API = function( callback ){

      arguments.caller.callee.context.name // ???

}
```

Is there a way to access the bound context for example `person.name` from the `API` function, without having to pass the context as another argument to the `API` ?

Notes

- The example code above is only for demo purposes, in the actual case person and API functions are not on the same context, so simply entering person.name in the API is not the right solution...
- We are looking for an ES5 solution, we are on a IE>=10 limitations

Comment: in ES6 yes with arrow functions `() => {}`

Comment: Scope, or *context* (`this`)? In short though, I don't think either is possible.

Comment: You want the method's context, scope is a different mechanism

Comment: @deceze mistake corrected. you and slebetman are correct

Comment: Basically, your function shouldn't depend on the context of a passed callback to begin with. That's an internal detail to the callback that your function should have no interest in. What context the callback has depends on its circumstances, which may change over time and should not be coupled to the needs of your function.